# Two versions of PHP on Apache (Windows) based on directory

Tags: php, windows, apache, version

I would like to run two versions of PHP (5.3 and 5.6) under Apache on a Windows Server.

The problem is the directory tree.

My tree is 
www_root/
-->Dir1
-->Dir2

www_root and Dir1 are on the same vhost (**www.domain.com and www.domain.com/Dir1**)

How can I run **PHP 5.6** on the "**www_root**" directory, PHP 5.6 on the "**www_root/Dir1**" and **PHP 5.3** on the "**www_root/Dir2**" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `htaccess` with `AddHandler`.
Create a `.htaccess` file on both folders and add the following according to the php version you want to use.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

---

You may also want to read [Apache, MySQL, PHP server on Windows with multiple, simultaneous PHP versions](http://www.dionysopoulos.me/apache-mysql-php-server-on-windows-with-multiple-simultaneous-php-versions.html)

Comment: Thanks.  But I want the two versions to run simultaneously.  The post you linked can only switch versions.

Comment: Thanks for your support.  Is it possible on the same vhost like www.domain.com and www.domain.com/Dir1 with diferent PHP versions